# insert array values into an empty dictionary

Tags: swift

I have an array = [14, 1087, 28474]. how am I suppose to make it like [fantasy, action, animation] where 14 = fantasy , 1087 = action and so on. I want to show only the string representation of those value to my ios label. Is there any way i can do that. Should I make an empty dictionary and if so then how am i suppose to generate the keys for those values inside the arrays

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't said what you have already tried, but a dictionary is probably the way to go.  If you make the dictionary a var, you can add to it later.  If you don't need to change it, define it as `let` as @Leo suggests

```
    var dict : [Int : String] = [
        14 : "fantasy",
        1087 : "action",
        28474 : "animation"
    ]

    let thisNumber = 1087
    let thisString = dict[thisNumber]
```

Comment: Swift is a type inferred language. Give it a try. BTW dict should be a constant also

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dictionary literal if your final goal is just to have a mapping from known numbers to known genres.

```
let dictionary = [14: "fantasy", 1087: "action", 28474: "animation"]
```

if you need to build the dictionary and add to it at run time you can loop through the array and add values to the dictionary with this syntax:

```
dictionary[22] = "genre"
```

Comment: I am a bit confused about the answer. Well let me clear it up again maybe I have explained it wrong. I generate the array from a json data, A = [14, 1087, 28474]. each of the elements represents a movie genre. I now need to show those genres as a string values showing in the label. I have the whole dictionary which gives a whole data of id as : 14 and name as : fantacy. I just dont know how to compare that array that I received with the dictionary that has been given to me so that I can compare the id with the received array value and print the name of the corresponding